# Fullcalendar eventDrop Timezone Issue

Tags: fullcalendar, momentjs

We provide the ability for a user to select their own timezone and call the following when a different timezone is selected (using moment.tz for the options)

```
$('#calendar2').fullCalendar('option', 'timezone', object.options[object.selectedIndex].value || false);
```

This works great when viewing appointments etc.  However, when a user tries to drag/drop an appointment, it appears to revert back to their "local" PC time to calculate the UTC time value on eventDrop

example:

fullcalendar timezone:  'America/New_York' (but my pc timezone is set to pacific)
Drag event 4pm apt to 12pm.  eventDrop

```
eventDrop: function(event,eventDelta,revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {    
   event.start.format()
}
```

Output:

```
2016-12-23T12:00:00-08:00
```

You can tell based on the -8:00 offset that it is getting this from my local PC and not from the timezone that was set to 'America/New_York' and it should be -5:00.  What is the best way to handle this?

UPDATE:  I figured this out using the following code.  Basically, you need to take care of converting the timezone yourself.  Fullcalendar does not do this for you.

```
strStartDate =  event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").toString()

 var start = moment.tz(strStartDate, $('[data-id="timezone-selector"]').find(':selected').val());

 objFCC.saveObject(event.appointmentId,  start.valueOf()  , mins, strResource, function(result, event)
```

Comment: Please check this link: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/issues/184

Comment: This is a good question, but could please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using jsFiddle or similar?  Thanks.